# 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH on Mac with Eclipse RED

Tags: robotframework

I've been trying to automate some basic stuff with Robotframework. Here is my configuration.

1. Python - 2.7.10
2. MAC High Sierra 10.13.2
3. Eclipse Oxygen with RED Editor

I've downloaded Geckodriver executable and put in under several places including usr/local/bin, folder on desktop

**Here is what i've tried**

Setup FFDriver   Set Environment Variable     webdriver.gecko.driver    Users/[my username]/Desktop/geckodriver

Setup FFDriver   Set Environment Variable     webdriver.gecko.driver    usr/local/bin/geckodriver

**and my test**

```
open browser    http://www.google.com    firefox
```

I've added usr/local/bin in PATH as well and still getting "geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH" error. The same happens with Chromedriver too. I am sure I must be missing something trivial here, can someone help me out please?

Comment: Have you confirmed that from the command line the WebDriver executable (Chome/FireFox) can be started from your project directory? The same applies as well when running your robot script from the command line. RED is only an editor and Robot Framework is a separate application that can be run from the command line.

Comment: a simple test is to go to the command prompt and type in "geckodriver". Does it execute or do you get "command not found"? Also, how are you starting RED? Are you starting it from a command prompt or double-clicking a desktop icon? The desktop icon may not be inheriting the PATH that you are setting.

Answer (score 1):

Launching the eclipse from command prompt, has fixed this issue. Yes, the PATH is not being inherited when launched from desktop icon.

Answer (score 0):

when you use Python. the best shortcut you can do is, put you 'geckodriver.exe' file in pythons script folder. and set the Script folder path in you system path. this will resolve your problem.